# Ubuntu 17.10: low resolution on external 2560x1440 monitor (Lenovo P24H) with AMD RV620 (FirePro V3700)

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm trying to setup an external monitor with the resolution of 2560x1440 with an ATI FirePro V3700 graphics card. The output of `lspci | grep VGA` is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620 GL [FirePro V3700]
```

After installing Ubuntu 17.10 the current resolution is 1920x1440 and I cannot change this via `Settings -> Devices -> Displays` to use the maximum resolution of 2560x1440.

[image]

I am assuming the graphics driver is *Radeon*, from the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver). I've also tried to create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it seems this configuration is not being loaded because it had no effect. The contents of this file is the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier    "AMD Radeon FirePro V3700"
    Driver        "radeon"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Lenovo ThinkVision P24H"
    HorizSync       30.0-62.0
    VertRefresh     50.0-70.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    Monitor        "Configured Monitor"
    Device        "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Modes    "2560x1440" "1920x1200" "1920x1080"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

From the graphics card [technical specs](http://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-ATI/FirePro_3D_V3700.html) I can see that this card can output a maximum of 2560x1600. Can anyone help me? Thank you.